# Scheduling a job in databricks Azure

Tags: azure-databricks

I want to schedule a databricks job that runs every day at 5:00 AM, 8:30 AM and 9:00 PM.
I am looking for cron syntax.

Comment: Please share the error or any blockage occurred while creating a schedule if you tried?

Comment: I have tried this 
0 0 5,8,21 ? * * 
But this runs at 5 am, 8 am and 9 pm. But instead of 8 I want it for 8:30 am.

Comment: I guess this cannot be done with single trigger, i suggest to go with 2 triggers for 5am,9pm and 8:30 schedule because minutes must be same for times to trigger through cron syntax.

Comment: How can we trigger it twice. Is it using cron syntax or something else.

Comment: Create two different schedule jobs One for 5am and 9pm to trigger the notebook and another job for 8:30am with cron syntax.

Comment: This will be hectic as I have more than 100 jobs to be created and if this is the case, I have to create 200 jobs. Isn't it possible in a single job.

Comment: Considering [this prompt](https://i.imgur.com/1osz3Ix.png), one possible solutions is to create 2 schedules.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a jobs in the **workflows** item.

[image]

- Create a new job

[image]

- Provide required inputs to a create job for Notebook.

[image]

Schedule a time to trigger the notebook in **Edit Schedule**

[image]

- Click on scheduled trigger type to schedule the time, provide `0 0 5,21 ? * *` as CRON syntax to run at 5:00AM and 9:00PM.

[image]

- Create another new job to trigger the notebook at 8:30AM, schedule `0 30 8 ? * *` as CRON syntax.

[image]
[image]

- Now the two jobs were run at expected times i.e 5:00AM, 8:30AM and 9:00PM.
  [image]

*Minutes must be same for all the timings to schedule a trigger to run the notebook with single job, as per the requirement there is no other option to run with single job we must go for two jobs.*